# Grant execute on specific type in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datatypes, permissions, subtypes

I have created a package and defined a type for collections as follows:

```
create or replace package <schema>.<package> as 

-------------------------------------
   type <type> is table of <something>;
-------------------------------------

...
   function <func>(
      ...
      <param> in <type>,
      ...
    )
      return pls_integer;
...
```

I have a user that has to call this function but can't because apparently they don't have the permission to execute `type` collection. I could solve it by

```
GRANT EXECUTE ANY TYPE TO <user>;
```

but I am bound by security protocols that says no user has to have access to any data, schema, blueprint or object unless they certainly have to. So I want to give the user explicit grant on specific type `<type>`, but calling the following statement results in error:

```
GRANT EXECUTE TYPE ON <schema>.<package>.<type> to <user>;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege
00990. 00000 -  "missing or invalid privilege"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant `EXECUTE` on package itself. If security is your main concern you may create a new package that has just types, but you cannot specify that a given user can access only some objects defined in package specification - either all or none.

Comment: I put types needed for each package inside packages for this reason, but the odd part is that the user already has execution grant on the package. I tried the `execute any type` and the error resolved, that made me think there is something special about types within packages.

Comment: `type <type> is table of <something>;`  - does user has permissions on `<something>` ? It may be the case .

Comment: Actually, `<something>` in this case is `varchar2(255)`, so I assume they have the permission.